# insert carriage return before a regular expression in a text file using unix shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, carriage-return

I have a messy text file (about 30 Ko) containing data that I have to reorganize using a shell script.
The file exibits a simple pattern : 
A "parameter number" (value between  10001 and 10999 ) is followed by several other values ( floats ). Values are separated by a space. 
I would like my file to be : 
on each line, a "parameter number" is followed by its values (only one "parameter number" in a line). Values are separated by a space.

My problem is easy to understand :

The "messy" file looks like that :

```
10001 x(1,1) x(1,2) ... x(1,n) 10002 x(2,1) x(2,2) ... x(2,n) 10003 x(3,1) x(3,2) ... x(3,n) [..and so on to..] 10999 x(999,1) x(999,2) ... x(999,n)
```

where `x(i,j)` are floats

I would like it to be :

```
10001 x(1,1) x(1,2) ... x(1,n) 
10002 x(2,1) x(2,2) ... x(2,n) 
10003 x(3,1) x(3,2) ... x(3,n) 
...
10999 x(999,1) x(999,2) ... x(999,n)
```

**I would like to write a bash script (or a simple command) that replace the "space" before the pattern `10[0-9][0-9][0-9]` (regex) by a carriage return.**

Bash script and regex are something  new for me and can't figure an easy solution.

I am thinking about using the bash `${string//substring/newsubstring}` parameter expansion but I still don't know how to say "the space that precedes the pattern `10[0-9][0-9][0-9]`" in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would like to write a bash script (or a simple command) that replace the "space" before the pattern 10[0-9][0-9][0-9] (regex) by a carriage return.

You could use sed.

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\(10[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\n\1/g' file
```

OR

```
sed 's/ \(10[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\n\1/g' file
```

In basic sed, capturing group is represented by `\(..\)`.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
0001 x(1,1) x(1,2) ... x(1,n) 10002 x(2,1) x(2,2) ... x(2,n) 10003 x(3,1) x(3,2) ... x(3,n) [..and so on to..] 10999 x(999,1) x(999,2) ... x(999,n) 
$ sed 's/[[:space:]]\(10[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\n\1/g' file
0001 x(1,1) x(1,2) ... x(1,n)
10002 x(2,1) x(2,2) ... x(2,n)
10003 x(3,1) x(3,2) ... x(3,n) [..and so on to..]
10999 x(999,1) x(999,2) ... x(999,n)
```

Comment: thx very much for this answer !
Another question : what does "\1/g" at the end of your command stands for ?  I also wanted to make the "carriage return" readable by windows but when I have replaced the "\n" by "\r/\n" an error occurs...
(NB: I am actually working on cygwin)

Comment: no, it would be like `sed 's/[[:space:]]\(10[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\r\n\1/g' file` . `g` is a modifier which helps to do a global match. Just try the above sed command with and without `g` modifier.